# EWS API get Sender name when Cc information is missing

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

In work we have service mailbox and suddenly started coming mails with attachement daily, no one know why and how to stop that and nobody need that.

So im writing deleting script and i dont know how to detect/find these emails, because Cc field is blank and email with same Subject from same email address is already coming but difference is between alias, how can i read information from the image ?

[image]

I need declare a SearchFilter like

```
SearchFilter subjectFilter =
                new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.?WHATHERE?, "JOBRUN <something@company.com>");
```

Thank you :-)

Comment: You need to refine your question. How do you discern these unwanted mails from "valid" senders?

Comment: i need to delete every email which have JOBRUN before address, its only different thing and i dont know how to read that info

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand you correctly, and based on your screenshot, you want to get those emails that have the string `JOBRUN` in their *Display Name* (not in their *Subject* as your variable name states).

Altough I'm not sure if the following does the filtering based on the email-address of the sender only or additionally based on the sender's displayname ([the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessageschema_members) is pretty poor...), you could try the following:

```
var filter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Sender, "JOBRUN");
```

Comment: Thank you i will try and let you know ! :-)

Comment: Too bad :( What you could still try is to debug your application and fetch one of those emails. In the debugger you should be able to retrieve the "right" property which holds the string JOBRUN which you could then use for your filter.